# Algorithmic question about making wordle in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to recreate WORDLE in c++. I have it working almost completely, there is just one thing I can't figure out how to do. Say the word is "erase" and the player types in "eerie". what should be happening is the first "e" should be green, the second grey, and the last green as well, but the way I have my code set up makes it so the answer given by the player is checked from left to right so instead of the response mentioned earlier, the player would receive the first "e" green, the second yellow, and the last grey. How can I change the code (listed below) to make it work correctly? I have been thinking of a solution for the past two days and still can't come up with anything. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

string pickword(int rand);
bool checkdict(string word, int rand);
string checkword(string ans, string word);

int main() {
  cout << "Hi welcome to WORDLE\n\n*Hit enter to start*";
  cin.ignore();
  int num = 0;
  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
  int random = 1 + (rand() % 5754);
  string guess;
  string word = pickword(random);
  // cout << endl << word;
  do {
    cout << "\033[37m" << "\nEnter a 5-letter word: ";
    cin >> guess;
    bool inLst = checkdict(guess, random);
    while (inLst == false) {
      cout << "\033[37m" << "\nThat's not in the word list.\nEnter a 5-letter word: ";
      cin >> guess;
      inLst = checkdict(guess, random);
    }
    checkword(guess, word);
    num++;
  } while ((num < 6) && (guess != word));
  if (guess == word) {
    switch (num) {
      case 1:
        cout << "\033[37m" << "\n\nHOW DID YOU DO THAT!!! You must be this generations Einstein!";
        break;
      case 2:
        cout << "\033[37m" << "\n\nDon't go showing off now!";
        break;
      case 3:
        cout << "\033[37m" << "\n\nWow! Mind BLOWN!";
        break;
      case 4:
        cout << "\033[37m" << "\n\nStill impresive. Great work!";
        break;
      case 5:
        cout << "\033[37m" << "\n\nCutting it a little TOO close, don't you think?";
        break;
      case 6:
        cout << "\033[37m" << "\n\nYIKES! That was a close one.";
        break;
    }
    if (num != 1)
      cout << "\033[37m" << "\nCongratulations, you guessed the word in " << num << " guesses.";
    else if (num == 1) {
      cout << "\033[37m" << "\nCongratulations, you guessed the word in just " << num << " guess!";
    }
  }
  else if (guess != word) {
    cout << "\033[37m" << "\nBetter luck next time. The word was: " << word;
  }
}

string pickword(int rand) {
  string string;
  ifstream ReadFile;
  ReadFile.open("words.txt");
  for (int i = 1; i <= rand; i++) {
        getline(ReadFile, string);
    }
  ReadFile.close();
  return string;
}

string checkword(string ans, string word) {
  cout << endl;
  string anslst[5];
  string wrdlst[5];
  string lstcpy[5];
  for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    anslst[i] = ans[i];
    wrdlst[i] = word[i];
    lstcpy[i] = wrdlst[i];
  }
  //Green = \033[32m
  //Red = \033[31m
  //Yellow = \033[33m
  for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    //for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
     // wrdlst[i] = lstcpy[i];
   // }
    if (anslst[i] == wrdlst[i]) {
      cout << "\033[32m" << anslst[i];
      wrdlst[i] = ".";
    }
    else if (anslst[i] == wrdlst[0] || anslst[i] == wrdlst[1] || anslst[i] == wrdlst[2] || anslst[i] == wrdlst[3] || anslst[i] == wrdlst[4]) {
      cout << "\033[33m" << anslst[i];
      if (anslst[i] == wrdlst[0]) {
        wrdlst[0] = ".";
      }
      else if (anslst[i] == wrdlst[1]) {
        wrdlst[1] = ".";
      }
      else if (anslst[i] == wrdlst[2]) {
        wrdlst[2] = ".";
      }
      else if (anslst[i] == wrdlst[3]) {
        wrdlst[3] = ".";
      }
      else if (anslst[i] == wrdlst[4]) {
        wrdlst[4] = ".";
      }
    }
    else if (anslst[i] != wrdlst[i]) {
      cout << "\033[31m" << anslst[i];
      wrdlst[i] = ".";
    }
  }
  cout << endl;
  return word;
}

bool checkdict(string word, int rand) {
  bool indict = false;
  string string;
  ifstream ReadFile;
  ReadFile.open("words.txt");
  while (getline(ReadFile, string)) {
    if (word == string) {
      indict = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  ReadFile.close();
  return indict;
}
```

Comment: Fear the magic number: `int random = 1 + (rand() % 5754);`

Comment: The txt file ("words.txt") has 5754 words in it. That value is so every time the program is run a different one of the words is chosen

Comment: That's what I figured, but it's the generated number's not actually used anywhere. If you read the file into a container at the start of the program, you can use the `size` of the container and eliminate the risk of reading outside the container if the file stores fewer than 5754 words or otherwise the reading craps out early. Anyway instead of 5754,  have a named constant hold the number so that the code becomes easier to read. Eg `constexpr int max_word = 5754;`

Comment: Sounds like you want to comparean excat match of the letters at each slot in the respective arrays. `anslst[1] == wrdlst[1]` rather than looping on `i` with `anslst[i] == wrdlst[1]` comparing all of the user's input letters against all of the  letters in the word from the list.

Comment: How about, first pass check for correct letter(s) in correct location(s). Remove those letters from the array. Then check (the remaining) letters for matches.